# Reloading a fragment state

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an android app that uses a set of 5 fragments, where you can only see one fragment at a time. Right now every time the menu button is clicked, I make a new fragment and put it into the view. However, I would like to be able to reload a saved fragment state. How am I able to do this?
For example, this is a bit of the code I am currently using to load one of said fragments.

```
case R.id.map_item:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MapFragment()).commit();
                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to reload a saved fragment state

Depends on how persistent state should be you can save your state in i.e. `onPause()` and load in `onResume()` of each of the fragments, or you can make your fragment's host (perhaps it's `Activity`) expose separate methods like `savePageState()` and `loadPageState()` and call it from said methods - that would simplify controlling stored state - you most likely want it to be not loaded when you open Activity for the first time (or you start it to do the job) etc.

Comment: Hi, could you explain more? What do you mean by "how persistent state should be". Also, how should I use onPause and onResume?

Comment: I do not know what are you doing so it may be required i.e. fragment state to stay regardless app is killed or not. Or from other hand you want the state to be gone once the task these fragments are for is completed. and you simply override `onPause()`/`onResume()` as any other method - call `super.....` and then do your job. [Here's fragment lifecycle diagram you seem to miss](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Comment: So specifically, for example I am trying to figure out how to have a user change the camera view on a map, then switch to another tab, then switch back so that the camera view is hasn't been reset to the default state. Another thing is that when a user clicks a button (which I've set up to only be able to be clicked once), and the user switches tabs, when he switches back the button still cannot be pressed.

Comment: as I already said - save your current state in `onPause()`. When use will return to the same fragment, `onResume()` will be called where you read your state (i.e. from shared preferences for example) and ensure all widgets reflect the state (i.e. you disable the button if read state i.e. `is_that_one_time_button_clocked` is `true` etc). So, in first place, you should keep track of the state of elements you want to stay persistent

Comment: Ok sounds good. Then I shouldn't be replacing the fragment with a new fragment every time I click the menu button in the mainactivity thread right? What should I do in terms of loading the fragment with supportfragmentmanager()?

Comment: We, will you be replacing or not does not really matter. If you save the state in persistent store (like sharedpreferences) then even you will recreate the fragment restored state it would read should make it pop up as it was before. But from other hand - maybe you should just consider adding all fragments to your layout (i.e. in `FrameLayout`) and then just show/hide them? It sometimes may have more sense than replacing fragments.

Comment: All the fragments are in a framelayout. Could you explain how to do show/hide for the fragments, specifically how the switch logic would work? When in the instantiation should I call show/hide for all the fragments?